Ubuntu installer not seeing Windows boot drive to dual boot Windows 11 with Ubuntu Cinnamon 24.04
I have created a USB stick with the verified .iso of Ubuntu Cinnamon 24.04. I boot into Ubuntu and proceed to try to install. When I get to the disk setup step, I do not have the option to install alongside Windows, only the options to erase and install and a manual installation. The SSD I have connected currently is my Windows boot drive.
EDIT: I have Windows set to never sleep, only the screen to turn off after 20 minutes or so. It is not encrypted. I have verified it is UEFI mode. // I had tried to find how to do the partitioning myself, but had not found that page @karel. I will attempt to give that a go tonight.

Is your Windows power options/hibernation turned off?  Is your Windows encrypted? Is this a UEFI mode or legacy (should be in same mode as Windows, but system settings may cause install media to boot the wrong way).   Add requested information to your original posting.

Does this answer your question? How to use manual partitioning during installation?
